# Trying to Add A Link to A Carousel

Tags: hyperlink, carousel, bootstrap-5

***SOLVED***
I Simply did not have the closing a tag at the end. Sheesh....

I need help. I'm still a student so still learning. Any help would be appreciated. I'm lost.
I'm using bootstrap5, adding a carousel ("With captions" https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/ for the full code.) to a page and a link in that slide on the h5.
After adding the link, the text went from white to blue and gives me this
"Cannot GET /WilliamVest/%E2%80%9CKeyWestPhotoGallery.html"
I've checked this address NUMEROUS times. Even said it out loud to myself. The link IS in the same folder as the rest of the project.
So why won't it work?
I tried to google and found "data-bs-target" does that have anything to do with it? Like I said, still new so still learning.

****Someone pointed out I missed the quotes in the link. Did not fix it.
I added that quote. It was discolored so I don't know where that came from but I think it's because you were right about the quotation style.
I commented that whole line out and started over. I just wanted to see the difference.
So now, the blue is gone in the lettering but now it won't even open another page to show an error. It does nothing.

First slide label
Key West Photo Gallery -->

This is my code snippet ---- KeyWestPhotoGallery.html is the link I'm trying to get to.

```
<!-- Carousel of Projects -->
  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="Images/palmLighthouse1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Key West Lighthouse">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5 class="display-2"><a href=“KeyWestPhotoGallery.html>Key West Photo Gallery</a></h5>
          <!-- <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p> -->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
<a href=“KeyWestPhotoGallery.html>
```

That is not a quote `"` as used in HTML, that is a Unicode [Left Double Quotation Mark](https://unicode-table.com/en/201C/) a.k.a. opening typographer's quote (a display character with no special meaning). So it thinks that is part of the URL that is why it is urlencoded into that address as `%E2%80%9C`

```js
let path = "/WilliamVest/%E2%80%9CKeyWestPhotoGallery.html"
console.log(decodeURI(path))
```

Solutions include the following:

- Remove it: `<a href=KeyWestPhotoGallery.html>` ([Unquoted attribute-value syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/syntax.html#attr-value-unquoted))
- Or, replace it adding the missing closing quote: `<a href="KeyWestPhotoGallery.html">` ([Double-quoted attribute-value syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/syntax.html#attr-value-double-quoted))
- Or, use single quotes: `<a href='KeyWestPhotoGallery.html'>` ([Single-quoted attribute-value syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/syntax.html#attr-value-single-quoted))

Comment: I tried that, but it still doesn't work. I tried your single quotes and that didn't work either. 
I added an accordion drop down below it to try an alternative linking method. The link works there, but not in the carousel.